# Requerir que un input esté vacío jquery validator blade

Tags: javascript, blade

estoy utilizando el script jquery validate para validar unos campos de la siguiente manera

```
$('#digest-report-form').validate({
                rules: {
                    meo_tool_url: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    google_maps_url: {
                        required: true,
                        url: true
                    },
                    recipients: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    business_types: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    location_id: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    name: {
                        required: false,
                        empty: true,
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: false,
                        empty: true,
                    },
                },
```

como verán, estoy intentando que los campos email y name estén vacíos al momento de enviar el formulario, ya que estos se añaden a un input oculto cuando los introduzco en un botón, sin embargo, el usuario debe insertar todos los datos, es decir, debe dejar esos campos vacíos obligatoriamente, no dejarlos con datos

Básicamente quiero hacer un inverso de los required, sin embargo no funciona, los envía simplemente

Cómo podría hacerlo? también me sirve validar a través del HTML que envíe vacíos los campos `email y name`

Comment: Disculpa, pero si no llenaras esa información, porque la colocas a vista de usuario, mostrara algo luego de que pase el proceso?

Comment: @FelipeUrcia no, los necesito vacíos, es que son unos inputs que utilizo para rellenar una tabla, lo que envío es la tabla y necesito que dejen esos campos vacíos indicando que los deben añadir a la tabla y no dejarlos así

Answer (score 1):

A ver si entiendo... Tienes un formulario y lo que deseas es evitar que el usuario interactúe con los campos de texto en él.

Si es así te sugiero simplemente [deshabilitarlos](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp) utilizando la propiedad de `disabled`.

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/url">
  <label for="texto">Digite su texto:</label>
  <input type="text" id="texto" name="texto"><br><br>
  <label for="deshabilitado">Bloqueado:</label>
  <input type="text" id="deshabilitado" name="deshabilitado" disabled><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Luego puedes usar el segundo botón (según lo que te entiendo) para llenar los datos cambiando la propiedad de `value` de ese texto.

UPDATE:

No escondes los datos, simplemente evitas que el usuario pueda escribir algo en ellos. Mira este ejemplo en el que uso un botón para rellenar los datos y el usuario los puede ver:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/url">
  <label for="texto">Digite su texto:</label>
  <input type="text" id="texto" name="texto"><br><br>
  <label for="deshabilitado">Bloqueado:</label>
  <input type="text" id="deshabilitado" name="deshabilitado" disabled><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="llenarCampos()" value="LLenar datos">
</form>
<script>
const llenarCampos = ()=>{
   document.getElementById("texto").value = "Datos del usuario";
   document.getElementById("deshabilitado").value = "Dato generado visible";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no amigo, esos campos los necesito yo para entrada a una tabla que genero yo mismo con un botón de agregar, estos campos los agrupo todos en un string para enviarlos, lo que realmente necesito es que estos campos queden totalmente vacíos cuando vaya a enviar el formulario, no esconderlos, el que tengo escondido es el del string que es el único que necesita validación

Comment: No quedan escondidos, quedan visibles con los datos que generes. Te actualicé mi respuesta con un ejemplo, los dejé vacíos para que concordasen con lo que dices. Estoy basándome en que usas el término `input`, y asumo que es un elemento `input` de tipo texto.